# Display different icons for different properties of a file (in the Windows Explorer)

Tags: windows-explorer, icons, regedit

Is it possible to set an icon for files with a specified extension ( **.abc** ) but not from an icon file? What I mean is if I can have a program (.jar or .bat) to decide the icon of these files. In the registry I’ve seen that the file icons for some extensions aren’t paths to images. Instead, they are paths to programs.
For example, image files (such as  **.jpg** shows a preview of themselves, instead of showing  an image that represents all the .jpg files. In this situation, I think that somehow, a program sets the icon for that file after getting the image. Video files show an image of the video, for example.
This is what I would like to do (with **.abc** files):

```
1.  If the file is in “C:\folder”, the icon for that file should be “C:\images\1.gif”.
2.  If the file is elsewhere, the icon for that file should be “C:\images\2.gif”.
```

This is my research:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/hh127427(v=vs.85).aspx : “Icons can also be assigned on an application-specific basis”. How?

Comment: As mentioned on that page, "Any file that contains an icon is acceptable, including .ico, .exe, and .dll files". I commented on your previous question as well that an icon handler shell extension would be required, but since you haven't cared to disclose what .abc is exactly no-one can suggest whether one already exists for that extension. (Given your specific requirements though I can pretty much guarantee no such extension exists, and you'll have to write it yourself.)